# Change the output result of np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 different .txt files and each of them contains `x,y,z` coordinates such: 
I read the content of those 3 files:

```
inputFileList = sorted(glob.glob(inputSourceDir + '/*.txt'), key=lambda x: (int(re.sub('\D', '', x)), x))
inputFileList = inputFileList[0:100]
inputTotalDataList = []
self.numberOfInputFiles = 0

for inputFilePath in inputFileList:
    inputDataInFile = np.genfromtxt(inputFilePath, dtype=float, delimiter=',')  # usecols= 0

    baseWithExt = os.path.basename(inputFilePath)
    base = os.path.splitext(baseWithExt)[0]

    inputTotalDataList.append(inputDataInFile)

    self.numberOfInputFiles = self.numberOfInputFiles + 1

    self.inputTotalData = np.array(inputTotalDataList)
    self.inputTotalData = self.inputTotalData.reshape(self.numberOfInputFiles * len(inputDataInFile), 3)
    print('TotalData: ', inputTotalData )
```

As output I get:

```
TotalData:  [[   7.29948 -187.854    760.208  ]
 [ -41.2607  -188.068    761.008  ]
 [ -13.2162  -193.675    771.235  ]
 [  35.361   -185.632    776.405  ]
 [ -58.8706  -188.025    785.184  ]
 [  12.8998  -196.275    789.446  ]
 [ -27.303   -198.127    791.598  ]
 [ -48.8703  -195.487    812.969  ]
 [  30.4976  -192.05     818.794  ]]
```

But I want to represent each read file like:

```
[[ 7.29948 -187.854    760.208  ]
 [ -41.2607  -188.068    761.008  ]
 [ -13.2162  -193.675    771.235  ]]
[[ 35.361   -185.632    776.405  ]
 [ -58.8706  -188.025    785.184  ]
 [  12.8998  -196.275    789.446  ]]
[[ -27.303   -198.127    791.598  ]
 [ -48.8703  -195.487    812.969  ]
 [  30.4976  -192.05     818.794  ]]
```

.
   .
   .

How can I convert my output to the desired result above?

Comment: Is your indentation off? (e.g. the last 3 lines?).  What's the purpose of the `reshape` line?  Did you check `self.inputTotalData` before that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
self.inputTotalData = self.inputTotalData.reshape(self.numberOfInputFiles * len(inputDataInFile), 3)
```

use the desired inner shape (3x3) and let it deduce the first (outer) dimension

```
self.inputTotalData = self.inputTotalData.reshape(-1, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Can I also convert that `self.inputTotalData np.array` to `dict` after reshaping?

Comment: Yes, you can. Assuming there is a list of `keys`, it can be done with `dict(zip(keys, self.inputTotalData))`